# How to post restful request with angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest

I'm using Nodejs and my route is something like that :

```
           router.get("/profil/:id",function (req,res) {
           });
```

I want to send data from my angular controller using $http service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send it by inject $http in your controller and

```
this.foo = function(id,date) {
  var  dataCal={};
  dataCal.Id=id;
  dataCal.date=date;
  var req = $http.post(url + "/dateUsageCalculate", dataCal);
  return req.then(this.handleSuccess, this.handleError);
}
```

and for the handleSuccess and handleError you can use.

```
  this.handleError = function(response){
    if(!angular.isObject(response.data) || !response.data.message){
      return($q.reject("An unknown error occurred."));
    }// Otherwise, use expected error message.
   return($q.reject(response.data.message));
  }


  this.handleSuccess = function(response){
      var result =  response.data
      return(result);           
  }
```